# If an upgraded North Korean army attack Current South Korea, how long could South Korea last?

Tags: warfare, alternate-reality

So in my story, North Korea is secretly given advanced technology and resources by an organization who want to use them to stir up conflict around the world for their goal. Let's say their tanks are equal to Russian T-90 or Chinese Type 99, their aircraft are well maintained Mig 29 and Su-33. They have laser anti-air and DF-21D carrier killer. But their industry infrastructure remain unchanged. Their soldiers are no longer malnourished and mind controlled to obey the Great Leader. However, their generals did not have the chance to test new combat doctrine and are still the same ones who wear a chestful of medals. North Korea is ordered by their benefactors to attack the South. The attack is sudden and unexpected. If they chose to isolate Seoul and trap most of the residents and remaining officials inside, while sweeping through the coast to severe the connection between Seoul and Busan, how quickly could they progress against what America and South Korea have currently deployed on South Korea homeland? In this Alternative Universe, China and Russian decided that they won't support the North Korea and choose to allow America, South Korea to conduct attack close to their border.

Comment: By "AU" do you mean Australia? Is N Korea prepared to use nuclear capabilities, is America? What's the UN reaction to this armed invasion? Why are you talking about America and South Korea conducting an attack, the rest of your question suggests it's North Korea that's the aggressor? At the moment your question needs defining very much more clearly, please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: I'd recommend taking this question to the meta sandbox. You may be surprised to find out just how many details are required to even start on this one. As the Romans found out at [Cannae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Cannae), wars can be enormously hard to predict.

Comment: South Korea has got ~500 000 of active military personnel. This amount of well fortified soldiers with modern equipment, as long as puts up a fight, would require quite a while (weeks?) to get neutralised. Even on day one, N. Koreans would start facing sorties launched from US bases in Japan and on first night B-2s from US mainland. Please specify exact number of N. Korea equipment.

Comment: Isnt this basically the Korean War but with more modern soldiers and weapons? At the beginning of that war the North Koreans had similar tech to the South I believe and their "secret" benefactor was the communist block.

Comment: There's an old saying : No plan survives contact with the enemy.  You're asking us to judge what a huge engagement like this (with unknown weaponry including "laser anti air" ???) would look like.  I couldn't tell you what would happen if a *platoon* of North Koreans attacked a platoon of South Koreans.  For every successful attack predicted in advance there's one that failed miserably.

Comment: @Chickensarenotcows AU -> Alternate Universe, from context.

Comment: Without naval or air superiority it's difficult to imagine how NK could keep its armies supplied south of the Han rivers.  So Seoul/Incheon would be the only prize worth taking and a siege of it could last weeks if not months and possibly result in an area no longer worth having.  All the while without the support of Russia or China NK command and supply are under continuous attack from non-stop UN sorties out of Japan and the Sea of Japan.  So the incursion could only be for a limited time.  Under these conditions what would a strategic win for NK would look like?

Comment: @StarfishPrime Just because Australia hasn't gotten involved, it doesn't mean Atlantis isn't going to wade in to put a stop to matters. Clarification required.

Comment: I've seen the ROK Army in action on exercises, And I've talked to South Koreans all over the peninsula. The DPRK Army would be met by near-fanatical resistance by *many millions* of South Koreans. They have no wish to fight their northern bretheren, but if the choice is forced upon them to fight or to submit to enslavement...they will generally fight very hard. Westerners talk about a *siege* of Seoul, ROK officers talk about the *trap* of Seoul that will chew up northern resources.

Comment: NK will surprise nuke every military installation it can, then proceed with ultimatum to deter America from interfering. They will try to submit ROK government with nuclear threats to the cities while throwing troops through non-urban areas. NK lacks warning radars and they have to hair-trigger missile fleet so any American attack likely to trigger an all-out nuclear strike against ROK population.